# Как защитить файл от повреждения при отключении питания?

Tags: c#, xml

Программа хранит ряд настроек в xml-файле. Если в момента записи настройки отключается питание компьютера, содержимое файла пропадает (сам файл остается, но если открыть - он пустой). Появилась идея сохранять изменения во временный файл, а затем переносить их в основной. Тогда, теоретически, должен повредиться только один из файлов при сбросе питания. Но на деле пропадает содержимое обоих файлов. Причина в коде? Или сам подход неправильный?
Сохранение временного файла и его копирование в файл-оригинал представлено ниже:

```
StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(FileName_);
BlockFile.WaitOne();
xmlDoc.Save(streamWriter);                    
BlockFile.Release();
streamWriter.Dispose();
File.Copy(FileName_, FileName, true);
```

В настоящее время код метода выглядит так:

```
static public void SetValueOfParameter(string nodeName, string parameterName, string valueOfParameter)
{            
    BlockFile.WaitOne();
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(FileName))
    {
        xmlDoc.Load(streamReader);
        XmlElement xRoot = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNode node = xRoot.SelectSingleNode(nodeName);
        node.SelectSingleNode(parameterName).InnerText = valueOfParameter;
        streamReader.Close();
        streamReader.Dispose();
    }
    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(FileName_))
    {
        xmlDoc.Save(streamWriter);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        streamWriter.Close();
        streamWriter.Dispose();
    }

    FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(FileName_);
    if (fInfo.Exists && fInfo.Length>0)
    {
        if (File.Exists(FileName))
        {
            File.Copy(FileName_,FileName,true);
        }
    }
    BlockFile.Release();
}
```

Вместо File.Copy(FileName_,FileName,true); было испробовано удаление/перемещение. Эффект тот же - два файла пустые. Кэширование диска снято

Comment: Попробуйте переименование или перемещеие файла. при копировании файла происходит то же что и просто при записи. А при переименовании только изменение записи в каталоге. причем сначала переименуйте старый в какой нибудь .old, а потом новый к обычное имя. между этими операциями хорошо бы буфера диска скинуть (хз как оно может в C# делаться)

Comment: А просто применять `flush()` после каждой записи не пробовали?

Comment: пробовали(((( не помогает

Comment: Укажите `StreamWriter` свойство `AutoFlush=true` - должно помочь

Comment: @Barmaley к сожалению, не помогло. Все больше прихожу к мысли, что проблема не в коде, а в особенностях жесткого диска, о которых я пока не знаю

Comment: В линуксе есть такая штука как fsync, которая не может не быть продублирована (возможно, под другим названием) в windows / стандартной библиотеке c#. После такого системного вызова можно быть уверенным, что данные успешно сбросились на диск, что позволит вам отталкиваться от инвариантов.

Comment: @etki FlushFileBuffers. Она вызывается при закрытии файла, и, как и fsync, может не пробить дисковый кэш на запись

Comment: @PashaPash fsync как раз таки гарантирует, что данные уже на диске. Пишут про некоторые проблемы с метаданными директории, но запись в файл является безопасной.

Comment: @etki The fsync() implementations in older kernels and lesser used filesystems does not know how to flush disk caches. Топикастер в таком вот положении - у него кэш записи отключен, файл закрыт, все флюшнулось - значит данные должны лечь на диск. Скорее всего диск шалит.

Comment: @PashaPash older kernels же, да и в доке *Due to disk caching interactions within the system, the FlushFileBuffers function can be inefficient when used after every write to a disk drive device when many writes are being performed separately.*, что явно намекает на то, что система при этом вызове ожидает сброс на диск всего кэша диска. Я пока что думаю, что с файлом шалит кто-то другой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xml заменили на базу sqlite. Все наладилось

Comment: В [документации](https://sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) sqlite раздел 6.0, четвёртый абзац: _Apparently some manufactures of IDE disks have controller chips that report that data has reached the disk surface when in fact the data is still in volatile cache memory in the disk drive electronics._ Ни одна СУБД ничего не может с этим поделать. Так что имейте в виду: данные могут повредиться и с sqlite.

Comment: Спасибо за здоровый пессимизм)) По крайней мере, мне не удалось поймать момент, чтобы данные повредились. В то время, как с xml это происходило в 10 случаях из 10 (учитывая мою сноровку попадать в нужный момент). Так что прогресс очевиден. Я теперь хоть сплю спокойно, а не проверяю каждые два часа по teamwiever, не вырубали ли свет у клиентов. Хотя, конечно, очень интересно, в чем же заключался корень проблемы. Времени дальше копать это нет.

Answer (score 6):

Судя по описанию проблемы - пропаданию данных уже после того, как они были записаны на диск (а они были записаны, т.к. вы смогли скопировать файл) - у вас включено кэширование записи на диск. Проверить можно в свойствах диска в Device Manager.

Кэширование записи безопасно только на дисках с автономным питанием (рейдах с батарейкой). Именно поэтому оно отключено по умолчанию. Если у вас обычный десктопный диск - данные будут теряться, и из кода на C# вы это никак не поборете.

Comment: Галочка действительно стояла, но после ее снятия ничего не изменилось

Comment: @naf: А вы перегрузились?

Comment: Да. Боюсь, перезагрузок на тестовом компьютере у меня даже больше, чем нужно. Уже раз 20 за день

Comment: @naf снятие галки должно полностью отключить кэширование. Вы же не в момент записи перезагружаетесь (точный момент вы все равно не поймаете) а уже после нее, вручную. Проверьте содержимое файла любым текстовым редактором сразу после завершения записи - если данные есть, и пропадают после этого по ресету - значит кэш все еще включен

Comment: @naf т.е. вы или галочку не сняли, или apply не нажали, или сняли ее не на том диске :)

Comment: @PashaPash мне, честно говоря, больше вас хочется, чтобы дело было в чертовой галочке

Comment: @naf: А может быть, у вас переписывает содержимое файла какой-то другой ваш код? Поставьте точку останова и загляните в файл сразу после записи.

Comment: Где-то когда-то я читал, что некоторые контролёры жёстких дисков не сбрасывают буфера даже при прямом приказе от ОС. Были такие проблемы у фирм разработчиков СУБД. В общем, нужно смотреть данные конкретной модели харда - может автору "повезло" и у него как раз такая модель. @naf

Comment: @VladD без перезагрузки пропажи файла никогда не было

Comment: @Alexander Petrov тот случай, когда программирование вместо магии начинает напоминать мистику

Comment: @naf скачайте утилиту для управления кэшем с https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/811392/obtain-the-dskcache.exe-tool-to-configure-the-power-protected-write-cache-option, запустите (под админом) и посмотрите настройки кэша. вдруг у вас все-таки включен Power Protect для диска

Comment: @PashaPash Спасибо за утилиту. Текущие настройки:
Write Cache is disabled
Power Protect is disabled

Comment: @PashaPash Хотя проблема, определенно, в жестком диске. Провели такой тест - файл-копию сохраняем не на диск, а на флешку. После сбоя питания на флешке корректный документ, а на диске - пустой

Comment: @naf а что за диск?

Comment: @PashaPash Диск - Seagate ST500LT012

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую сделать так:

1. Вы сохраняете новый файл с именем settings_new.xml
2. В случае успеха (проверка файла settings_new.xml на существование и ненулевую длину) удаляете файл settings.xml
3. Переименовываете файл settings_new.xml в settings.xml (можно так же скопировать и удалить оригинал)
4. При новом запуске приложения сначала ищете файл settings_new.xml. Если он существует и не пуст, значит произошел сбой питания или некорректное завершение работы программы. В этом случае доделываете операции 2 и 3.

Если вы выполните этот алгоритм, то при любом сбое вы будете уверены настройки не пропадут.

Comment: Эээ... И как вы можете гарантировать, что данные реально сброшены на диск, а не висят в кэше?

Comment: На уровне .NET CLR метод StreamWriter.Close() должен вызвать запись буфера на диск и закрыть объект. Если этот метод не вызвать, все равно вы не сможете переименовать файл (я допускаю что компилятор даст переименовать, но тогда он перед этим закроет объект сам).

На уровне Windows - насколько я помню работу с кэшем, при обращении к этому файлу (проверка на существование и длину) произойдет завершение записи перед ответом.

Comment: Ваш ответ - это длинный пересказ кода топикастера словами. Т.е. Он делает то де самое - и получает два пустых файла.  вызов Close должен записать на диск и закрыть объект. Метод Copy, который топикастер вызывает, точно проверяет и существование и длину :). Но если в системе включено кэширование записи - то данные просто физически не лягут на диск. Хотя все вызовы будут показывать что файл есть, давно закрыт и надежно сохранен.

Comment: У меня был примерно такой же алгоритм, только без проверки существования и размера. Однако дополнительная проверка, к сожалению, не помогла. По прежнему файлы пустые.

Comment: А скажите, как вы делаете проверку отключения питания?
Вы же не можете попасть в ту же долю милисекунды когда идет запись на диск?

Comment: @Ivan Kramarchuk Совершаю действие, которое приведет к изменению настроек и в этот момент отключаю питание. Я понимаю, что попасть в миллисекунду, когда идет запись, невозможно. Но тем не менее, есть интервал (по ощущениям секунды 2), если в него попасть, файлы стираются. Если подождать 3-4 секунды и выключить, все будет нормально. Файл остается такого же размера, как и был (ок. 3 Кб), но пустой. Открываю его в winHex - все полностью затерто нулями. Если питание не пропадает, файл никогда не теряется (программа отрабатывала больше месяца непрерывной работы без сбоев)

Comment: @VladD ну API для этого вполне существует: *[This includes writing through or flushing a disk cache if present.](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fsync)*

Comment: @etki: «The fsync() implementations in older kernels and lesser used filesystems does not know how to flush disk caches.», это раз. А во-вторых, SSD, как я слышал, может вполне заявлять, что данные записаны, но в реальности записывать их позже. С понятными последствиями. Впрочем, искренне надеюсь, что это ложные слухи.

Comment: @VladD ну я в первую очередь про то, что механизмы для этого существуют (это вообще часть [SATA API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_buffer#Cache_control_from_the_host)), и необходимость подобных гарантий слишком велика, чтобы хоть какая-то популярная ОС не предоставляла их; older kernels, вероятно, совсем older, потому что на fsync как на точку коммита опираются далеко не первый год. Некоторые SSD конечно могут так делать для имитации скорости, но все разумные производители, конечно, не будут это делать как раз из-за нарушения гарантии "fsync прошел - данные сохранены".

Comment: @etki: Я что-то не сильно уверен в этой гарантии: http://stackoverflow.com/a/706688/276994

Comment: @VladD боюсь, не готов подписаться без написания полноценного test suite и его прогонки на основных моделях, но, думаю, с восьмого года многое должно было измениться в лучшую сторону, и внутренний перфекционист отказывается верить, что условный интел игнорирует команда сброса буфера ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

Могу еще предложить не такой красивый, но гарантированно сохраняющий данные вариант:

1. Создайте папку settings, сохраняйте файлы туда с timestamp, например 1494856800.xml
2. При запуске программы ищите наиболее новый файл (максимальный timestamp) с ненулевой длинной.
3. Удаляете все файлы кроме найденного (эту операцию для надежности можно поменять на "Удаляете все файлы, кроме 10 последних")

UPD:
Добавил пример кода:

```
        static public void SetValueOfParameter(string nodeName, string parameterName, string valueOfParameter)
    {
        // BlockFile.WaitOne();
        string old_filename = get_setting_filename();
        string new_filename = DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc().ToString();
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(old_filename))
        {
            xmlDoc.Load(streamReader);
            XmlElement xRoot = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNode node = xRoot.SelectSingleNode(nodeName);
            node.SelectSingleNode(parameterName).InnerText = valueOfParameter;
            streamReader.Close();
            streamReader.Dispose();
        }
        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(new_filename))
        {
            xmlDoc.Save(streamWriter);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
            streamWriter.Dispose();
        }
        remove_old_files();
        // BlockFile.Release();
    }

    static public string get_setting_filename()
    {
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo("settings");
        FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.xml");
        DateTime min_date = DateTime.MinValue;
        string filename = "";
        // ищем не пустой файл с максимальной датой
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            // 4 - Чтобы файл не состоял только из символа окончания файла
            if (file.LastWriteTimeUtc > min_date && file.Length > 4)
            {
                min_date = file.LastWriteTimeUtc;
                filename = file.Name;
            }
        }
        return filename;
    }

    static public void remove_old_files()
    {
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo("settings");
        FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.xml");
        DateTime min_date = DateTime.MinValue;
        int count_save_files = 10;
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files.OrderBy(f => f.LastWriteTime).Reverse().ToList())
        {
            // Проверяем что файл не пустой
            if (file.Length > 4)
            {
                // Не удаляем файлы настроек за последние сутки, независимо от количества
                if (file.LastWriteTime < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
                {
                    // Сохраняем 10 последних файлов (помимо последних суток)
                    if (count_save_files > 0)
                    {
                        count_save_files--;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        File.Delete(file.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Удаляем любые поврежденные файлы
                File.Delete(file.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Добавил пример кода. Разумеется для продакшена нужно оптимизировать, например удаление старых файлов перенести в старт программы.

Answer (score 0):

Доброго времени суток! Последовательность должна быть такой:

---

**Вариант 1:**

**Открытие и работа с файлом**

**1**) Проверяете существование `~settings.xml`

**1.1**) Проверяете валидность файла `~settings.xml`

**2.1**) Если существует и валиден то открываете его с доступом на чтение иначе удаляете его и переходите к пункту 3

**2.2**) Открываете файл `settings.xml` с доступом на запись

**2.3**) Записываете содержимое файла `~settings.xml` в `settings.xml`

**2.4**) Закрываете файлы. Удаляете `~settings.xml` (далее работает по пунктам следующим пунктам)

**3**) Если файл `~settings.xml` не существует, то открываете файл `settings.xml` с доступом на чтение

**4**) Создаете файл `~settings.xml` и открываете с доступом на запись

**5**) Работаете с файлом `~settings.xml`

**Сохранение результатов**

**1**) Закрываете оба файла

**2**) Открываете файл `~settings.xml` с доступом на чтение и файл `settings.xml`  с доступом на запись

**3**) Перезаписываете файл `settings.xml` содержимым файла `~settings.xml`

**4**) Закрываете оба файла. Удаляете `~settings.xml`

---

**Вариант 2:**

**Открытие и работа с файлом**

**1**) Проверяете существование `~settings.xml`

**1.1**) Проверяете валидность файла `~settings.xml`

**2.2**) Если `~settings.xml` существует и валиден то удаляете `settings.xml` иначе удяляете его и переходите к пункту 3

**2.3**) Копируете файл `~settings.xml` и создаете новый файл с названием `settings.xml`

**2.4**) Удаляете `~settings.xml` (далее работает по пунктам следующим пунктам)

**3**) Если файл `~settings.xml` не существует, то копируете `settings.xml` и создаете новый файл с названием `~settings.xml`

**4**) Работаете с файлом `~settings.xml` *(На этом этапе можно открыть файл `~settings.xml` с доступом на запись)*

**Сохранение результатов**

**1**) Закрываете файл `~settings.xml`

**2**) Удаляете файл `settings.xml`

**3**) Копируете файл `~settings.xml` и создаете файл с названием `settings.xml`

**4**) Удаляете `~settings.xml`

---

*Этот алгоритм должен предотвратить полную потерю данных*